# How can I find the IP addresses of devices on my local network?

Tags: networking, scanner, ip, nmap

Is there any way I can find out the IP addresses on my network?

For example my home router is 192.168.5.1 and it is connected to an airos device the IP of which is 192.168.1.20, and the airos device is connected to a mikrotik device.

How can I know what the IP of the mikrotik device is, and the IP addresses of the devices that are above it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a list of connected devices on your router, so you should probably check that first if you have access.

Of course, that won't help you if you want to look up subnets on connected devices. So if that is what you are after, I would suggest that you try to connect to the device that is making the subnet and check what IP you get from there. Then you could scan for other devices using something like nmap.

But like, in general, you won't be able to access subnets without being part of it.

Comment: i have a wireless connection to the mikrotik device but i need to know how to get it's ip

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with that device, but I don't think it will tell you it's IP if you are not on the same subnet. By that, I mean that you and it is connected on the same network as the IP was assigned on. it would be pretty easy if you had a shell on the device tho.

Comment: but yea if you want the IP of the device on the same network, then just either scan with nmap or if you have your phone connected, use the app Fing